# Checking if a string is a hexadecimal value

Tags: c++

I have char whose value is 183 while doing rtf parsing. This is a special character .,

When i created a string out of it, i will get a hexadecimal string \xb7, which is a hexadecimal string. This is a one length string. 
How to determine that the string prep rend with \x or it is a hexadecimal string.

```
string substr(1,char);
cout<<substr<<substr.length();
```

Regards

Comment: Problem not clear. What does your code snippet mean?

Comment: i mean the substr value is \xb7, how can i check it is hexadecimal value. I cannot check by seeing \x prepends as the string is one entity.